# Understanding the symbolic computation of a derivative

Tags: programming-languages

I've been watching the [sicp videos lectures](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/) by Hal Abelson and Gerald Jay Sussman and am lost on lecture 3b. Can someone explain to me what's going on in this video?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X21cKVtGvYk

What is numerical approximation vs exact expression?

Comment: Do you know derivatives from calculus?

Comment: Please ask a specific question. Nobody, *nobody*, is going to watch a 45-minute video and explain everything in it to you.

Comment: not really well. can i skip this lecture?

Comment: The concepts are important. Maybe you should spend some time learning what a derivative is, even if you do that superficially. All you really need is to know is how it is computed, and that is not very hard. If you are doing science in college,  you have to learn it, imho. I learned it in high school.

Comment: When asking for clarification, a video is a pretty bad reference in
most cases. It is better to ask about a specific point in a book,
especially one that is easy to get. The Abelson-Sussman book is well
known and furthermore available on their site in PDF. It is also
organized in relation with the videos (section 2.2 for your
question). It makes it easier to answer and saves considerable time.
Always think of the time you are asking from other people.  That is
probably the main reason for the downvotes on your question.

Comment: Ok. I'm going to review mit's calculus lectures and then try this lecture again.

Answer (score 1):

After watching a whole minute with the speakers off.

It is using the language Lisp, or more probably Scheme, which is very close, to program a system that does calculus. For example it can take a function on the reals and compute its derivative. The function being differentiated is also written in Lisp. This is permitted by the fact that all Lisp entities, including programs, have a syntactic representation that can be manipulated by Lisp programs. This is actually where the idea of abstract syntax (tree) comes from, even though it is most rudimentary in Lisp. It permitted to write tools to transform programs, or to compute new programs (such as the derivative), and then maybe execute them, which led to all kinds of applications.
If you see a relation with Turing machines taking the Gödel number of other Turing machines as argument ... there is hope.
BTW The book by Abelson and Sussman is excellent reading, even though it is old.